# How to Decompile a from xcode deployed App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, compilation

I have written a simple calculation App and had always tested it on my IPad, it's necessary for another Project from me.
But i forgot to commit the Project to my remoted git Repo an formatted the Disk. Now I only have the deployed App Version on my IPad and I would realy like to know if it is possible to restore somehow the source Code. 
To write this App again would take me Days.

Comment: Maybe time to consider implementing a backup strategy ? Cheap external drive with Time Machine, perhaps ? And/or something like CrashPlan ?

Comment: I'm already write this calculation steps a second time. It seems there are no other ways. A hard lesson for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max what you can achieve is to get the assembly code.

Getting the Objective-C source code from binary is not possible since there are indefinite number of ways to represent the same assembly.

Comment: The Assembly Code wouldn't help me since it would take more time translate the assembly to source Code. The Only Thing I have now is the XCAppdata Container file, but it also doesn't help me

Answer (score 1):

not like .swf file of adobe flash, the binary file structure of iOS is not open source ... ..., so i think it's so hard even impossible to get the objective-c or swift source code from the binary file ...